# Artifactory plugin in Gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am trying to use artifactory in gradle.

this is my build.gradle (which was generated from the UI in the artifactory website) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://avra_artifactory:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.9')
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'artifactory'
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

but for some reason i get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'GradleConfiguration'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.0.9.
     Required by:
         :GradleConfiguration:unspecified
      > Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

GradleConfiguration is the name of the project which the build.gradle resides.

Can someone explain why i get this error?

Comment: can you resolve the missing artifact from avra_artifactory?

Comment: what do you mean? just explicitly download it from the artifactory site?

Comment: yes. make sure that (1) the server is accessible from the build machine (2) the required artifact can be resolved from the server - org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.0.9

Comment: where can i find  org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.0.9 ? I cant see it in the Artifacts Tab - > repositories browser.  I didnt explicitly wrote that in the build.gradle, it is generated from the site.

Comment: http://avra_artifactory:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/2.0.9/build-info-extractor-gradle-2.0.9.jar

Comment: ok, yes  the file is accessible from the build machine and can be resolved from the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87153/discussion-between-drorb-and-avra).